# How to search for headings all the way to the root heading (and preferably file name)

Tags: org-mode, search, header-line

I am new to emacs, and org-mode pulled me away from vim. I am getting a hang of it. One thing I am missing a lot is a **hierarchical search in emacs**. I wrote a python script for that in vim, and I am looking for a solution in emacs (org-mode).

Let me explain. Let us say, here is the file:

```
* People
** Software related help
*** John
*** Amit
** Personal
*** John
*** Mike
* Project
** With Mike
*** Website development
```

When I am searching for a heading, I usually know I am searching for `mike`, but once I see that there are too many search results (I use '**swiper-all**), I want to **narrow the search based what the child headings and parent headings contain**. In this case, I might want to extend the search to `mike people` or `mike project` based on what kind of heading I am searching for.

In other words, if each heading is a node in the tree, I want to **search not only in the node, but in the concatenation of all nodes up to the root**. (See a couple other nice-to-haves below.)

Is there any solution or **package avaiable for this**? If not, can you point me to **how to go about writing** a script/package for this?

---

Nice to haves:

1. Ideally, the **file name would be considered as the level zero heading**.
2. Ideally, the **order of words in the search term does not matter**. I sometimes don't remember if I wrote `With Mike` below `Project` heading, or wrote `Project` below `Mike` heading. In either case, I want to just search for `mike project` and be able to find what I am looking for.

Comment: I don't know about a ready-made package for it. But this can be useful to you: https://github.com/ndwarshuis/om.el

Comment: As you have swiper you should have counsel-outline, try that one. Helm must have something as well. With ivy it's possible to ignore the order of the words, look for ivy–regex-ignore-order in the documemtation. Counsel-outline checks the current file only.

Comment: @Hubisan: Thanks for the counsel-outline reference. It is an alias for `counsel-org-goto` and that lead me to `counsel-org-goto-all`, which does the search across all files. I am not sure which files it searches in. Probably all agenda files. Or open buffers (I need to check). I will look into ignoring the order of words.

Comment: @Hubisan: The combination of `counsel-org-goto-all` and `ivy–regex-ignore-order` worked perfectly for me. The only thing missing is now the "Nice to have #1". Thanks for helping me.  If you write this up quickly as an answer, I would definitely accept your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have [ivy](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper) installed you can use either `counsel-org-goto` (current buffer only) or `counsel-org-goto-all` (all currently opened org buffers). Both show the outline path for each heading and therefore let you search hierarchically:

[image: searching with counsel-org-goto]

> Remark: Those commands should also work for `emacs-lisp-mode`,
>   `markdown-mode` and `latex-mode`.

### Ignore search order

To ignore the search order you can customize the [ivy completion styles](https://oremacs.com/swiper/#completion-styles) for those commands:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'ivy-re-builders-alist '(counsel-org-goto . ivy--regex-ignore-order))
(add-to-list 'ivy-re-builders-alist '(counsel-org-goto-all . ivy--regex-ignore-order))
```

[image]

### Add filename

To add the filename at the beginning you can advice `counsel-outline-candidates`:

```lisp
(defun my-add-filename-to-counsel-outline-candidates (candidates)
  "Add the filename at the beginning for CANDIDATES from `counsel-outline-candidates'."
  (mapcar
   (lambda (candidate)
     (let* ((marker (cdr candidate))
            (filename (buffer-file-name (marker-buffer marker)))
            (filename-abbreviated (when filename (concat (abbreviate-file-name filename) " ")))
            ;; Use this if you want the buffer name. It's a bit shorter.
            ;; (buffername (buffer-name (marker-buffer (cdr candidate))))
            )
       (cons (concat filename-abbreviated (car candidate)) marker)))
   candidates))

(advice-add 'counsel-outline-candidates :filter-return #'my-add-filename-to-counsel-outline-candidates)
```

[image: counsel-org-goto with filenames]

Answer (score 1):

For Doom Emacs (with vertico) users there is `consult-org-heading` command and it's mapped to `SPC m .` by default. Works in current buffer only.

[image: consult-org-heading]

Search with any word order:

[image: searching]